# Is there a way to avoid javascript filtering on HTML files stored into a user's locker?

Tags: desire2learn

I'd like to store HTML files in a D2L LE user's locker, but I'd like to avoid the javascript filtering that the LE does. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

With only a few exceptional locations, scripts in user-provided HTML content get stripped out at or before render time for security reasons. The user locker is not, I believe, one of those exceptions.